# Show your reputation gain in each question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

I think it would be great that at every question there would be the reputation that you have gain with your participation on it.

Example 1: you make an edit on it (+2), your answer got accepted (+15), your answer got vote up (+10), you down vote an answer (-1). 
So, in somewhere in the screen there would be +26

Example 2: you submit an answer, it gets down voted (-2) three times.
So, in somewhere in the screen there would be -6

([What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation))

**Update:**

As show by a fellow, [you can sort your reputation by post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864167/jeroen-vannevel?tab=reputation&sort=post). The thing is that it still splits your reputation by dates, so if you have reputation on the same post but on different dates, it shows separated.

Then maybe, what it's better is to eliminate that group by date, when you sort by post.

Here is the prove:
Notice that the same post (Scroll horizontally....) appears twice
[image: Here is the prove]

Comment: I changed this to [tag:feature-request]. It looks like an FQ, quacks like an FQ, it is an FQ.

Comment: But to what end? Why is it important how much reputation one gained on a specific question, what does it matter?

Comment: Your example 1 doesn't seem like a useful number to me. That's combining numbers from three different posts just on the basis that they are from the same question. Those numbers are not related to each other, and a combined number would be useless and confusing. But further, you haven't explained *why* you want this number? How would seeing this number benefit you? How would it improve the community's usage of the site? Just because? Because that's not a good reason to implement something like this.

Comment: @animuson off topic, just in case you didn't see it: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1746425#1746425

Answer (score 4):

Is it really necessary though?

In [the reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864167/jeroen-vannevel?tab=reputation&sort=post) you can already see most of this information grouped together if you combine the overview by 'post'.

This will group upvotes, downvotes and accepted answers by post; all you have left to do is add a suggested edit (+2) and possible downvotes by yourself (-1) to it. That's hardly complicated math.

[image]

I believe this is grouped enough to give you a quick overview of how you did on a question; your proposal gives me the feeling it would just duplicate existing information.

Comment: It is necessary. cause that sort by post is great, but still takes in consideration dates, so it splits the same post reputation on different dates. But if that would not happen, then you are right.
I'll make an edit.

Comment: Please read the edit on the question.

Comment: I can't say I'm particularly convinced this would be a helpful addition to the network. I don't see the benefit in this when you'll need a lot of conditions to be met to make it worth the effort to create this instead of letting the user just quickly calculate it himself. You also propose to incorporate suggested edits which aren't applicable to any user over 2000 rep so that's even less userbase targetted. I think you're focused too much on reputation: reputation is awesome but at one point it's just reputation and some questions, not the other way around.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at [my reputation by post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945/jmac?tab=reputation&sort=post).

I recently got over 200 upvotes on a post over 4 days. There are 82 events on a single day that total up to 190 reputation.

When this is split by days, it is clear why I only got 190 rep (I hit the rep cap). If they are not split by day but all put together, I would have 125 events or whatnot showing something like +500 reputation. And that wouldn't make any sense when someone in the future takes a look at it.

Even if that limitation was removed (that it was split by post and by date under the post), I don't see the benefit of having it personally -- I am more interested in the number of upvotes on one of my questions (and when they came in) rather than about how much reputation I got from a question, especially considering the cap.

Comment: Of course that would make sense. It means the rep cap was hit. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @dje, the rep cap is per-site per-day. If you group by posts without having a grouping by-day then there is no way to understand what the heck any of those numbers mean, or which events actually attributed to reputation. The current system demonstrates how rep is actually calculated, what is the merit of creating a system that intentionally obfuscates that connection?